# How smart is mmap?

Tags: macos, unix, linux-kernel, mmap

`mmap` can be used to share read-only memory between processes, reducing the memory foot print:

1. process P1 `mmap`s a file, uses the mapped memory -> data gets loaded into RAM
2. process P2 `mmap`s a file, uses the mapped memory -> OS re-uses the same memory

But how about this:

1. process P1 `mmap`s a file, loads it into memory, then exits.
2. another process P2 `mmap`s *the same file*, accesses the memory that is still hot from P1's access.

Is the data loaded again from disk? Is the OS smart enough to re-use the virtual memory even if "mmap count" dropped to zero temporarily?

Does the behaviour differ between different OS? (I'm mostly interested in Linux/OS X)

EDIT: In case the OS is not smart enough -- would it help if there is one "background process", keeping the file `mmap`ed, so it never leaves the address space of at least one process?

I am of course interested in performance when I `mmap` and `munmap` the same file successively and rapidly, possibly (but not necessarily) within the same process.

EDIT2: I see answers describing completely irrelevant points at great length. To reiterate the point -- can I rely on Linux/OS X to not re-load data that already resides in memory, from previous page hits within `mmap`ed memory segments, even though the particular region is no longer `mmap`ed by any process?

Comment: I am almost certain that the specification for `mmap` doesn't say anything about how OSes should back the memory. I am even almost certain that your first assumption is wrong too and that nothing says the OS _has_ to use the same physical memory for both processes.

Comment: @zneak: thanks, but my question is not a hypothetical what-if. i'm pretty sure there exists a concrete answer for the two OSes I mention.

Comment: I would be more like: 1) process A mmaps a file 2) process A reads/writes to the mmaped region, causing the kernel to "fault in" the memory from the file 3) Maybe there is memory pressure, causing the memory to be "faulted out" until process A needs it again. 4) process A needs the memory again, it is reloaded 5) process A munmaps the memory 6) process B mmaps the file 7) process B reads/writes to the memory, if it's still in the buffer-cache it doesn't need to be reloaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The presence or absence of the contents of a file in memory is much less coupled to `mmap` system calls than you think. When you `mmap` a file, it doesn't necessarily load it into memory. When you `munmap` it (or if the process exits), it doesn't necessarily discard the pages.

There are many different things that could trigger the contents of a file to be loaded into memory: mapping it, reading it normally, executing it, attempting to access memory that is mapped to the file. Similarily, there are different things that could cause the file's contents to be removed from memory, mostly related to the OS deciding it wants the memory for something more important.

In the two scenarios from your question, consider inserting a step between steps 1 and 2:

- 1.5. another process allocates and uses a large amount of memory -> the `mmap`ed file is evicted from memory to make room.

In this case the file's contents will probably have to get reloaded into memory if they are mapped again and used again in step 2.

versus:

- 1.5. nothing happens -> the contents of the `mmap`ed file hang around in memory.

In this case the file's contents don't need to be reloaded in step 2.

In terms of what happens to the contents of your file, your two scenarios aren't much different. It's something like this step 1.5 that would make a much more important difference.

As for a background process that is constantly accessing the file in order to ensure it's kept in memory (for example, by scanning the file and then sleeping for a short amount of time in a loop), this would of course force the file to remain in memory. but you're probably better off just letting the OS make its own decision about when to evict the file and when not to evict it.

Comment: I thought it was obvious I am indeed asking `1.5. nothing happens -> the contents of the mmaped file hang around in memory.`, sorry for the confusion. Now, are you saying a new `mmap` can potentially re-use pages that were `mmap`ed, loaded, `munmap`ed some time earlier? (let's narrow it down to read-only mode on Linux/OS X).

Comment: Yes. If the file's pages are still in memory because it has been read/mapped/executed/preloaded/cached before, it **will** use them as is. If they're not there anymore because they were evicted, then it won't. It's that simple.

Comment: Thank you @Celada, that is a clear answer. I'll accept this if there's no contention.

Comment: The first process doesn't even have to `mmap()` the file - it could just `read()` it and the subsequent `mmap()` in the second process would still map the same page cache pages.

Comment: @caf are you sure? `read` uses a very different mechanism for file loading and caching compared to `mmap`, by design.

Comment: @user124114: Yes, at least in the case of Linux a buffered read (ie not `O_DIRECT`) from an ordinary file uses the page cache as its cache, which are the same pages that are mapped by mmap on an ordinary file.

Answer (score 3):

The second process likely finds the data from the first process in the **buffer cache**. So in most cases the data will not be loaded again from disk. But since the buffer cache is a cache, there are no guarantees that the pages don't get evicted inbetween.

You could start a third process and use mmap(2) and mlock(2) to fix the pages in ram. But this will probably cause more trouble than it is worth.

Linux substituted the UNIX buffer cache for a [**page cache**](http://tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-4.html). But the principle is still the same. The Mac OS X equivalent is called [**Unified Buffer Cache** (UBC)](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.126.1.93/1/).